# Permutation paired test with signed statistic

Tags: r, permutation-test, paired-data

I have one paired data from 7 patients:
$$(X_i ,Y_i)=\{(5,1),(-2,-4),(4,2),(-6,-3),(-3,-3),(-5,2),(3,1)\},\quad (i=1,\ldots, 7)$$

where $X$ means placebo $Y$ means the test drug.

My classmate asked me can we have permutation test for the sign statistics to identify $X < Y$.
I think the [coin](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/index.html) function can help me shuffle all the observation into $2^7$ permutations, and then we are not sure if we can just implement Wilcoxon rank sum statistics for each permutation to see the $p$-value?

So the question is how to shuffle all these data and implement the test?

Comment: What software are you using? Do you just want to understand teh algorithm conceptually?

Comment: I am using R for statistic analysis

Comment: I wondered if that was the `coin` you were referring to. So do you just need to know how to use coin to do a permutation test, or do you want to understand PT's conceptually?

Comment: I understand the permutation idea for comparing two groups, but not for paired. So that's why I think I need some advice here.

Comment: So you know that `wilcoxsign_test(Y ~ X, alternative="less", zero.method="Pratt", distribution="exact")` from package `coin` does what you want? Note that you have ties as well as zero-differences which can be handled in different ways.

Comment: If I want to use sign statistics, then i can do it in coin?

Answer (score 1):

If I take your data

```
c(5, 1, -2, -4, 4, 2, -6, -3, -3, -3, -5, 2, 3, 1)
```

And make both predictor(x) and subject(s) variables...

```
x <- factor(rep(c('placebo', 'drug'), 7))
s <- factor(rep(1:7, each = 2))
```

then you could do a permutation test with `coin` package `wilcoxonsign_test`

```
 wilcoxsign_test(y ~ x| s, distribution="exact")
```

Comment: it should be different than sign test, right?

Comment: Asymptotically a sign test and a permutation sign test are the same.  The result could be different, but it could also be the same.

Comment: if H0:drug = active H1: drug > active, then i can just put alternative='greater' in the commend?

Comment: you should try that

Comment: @user1489975, if you have found this answer helpful, you should consider upvoting it (by clicking on the upward facing normal distribution), & accepting it (by clicking on the check mark to the left of it).